# face skin on camera layout

Tags: android, layout, camera, face-detection

Hi I'm developing a little app that app that uses `Android.Media.FaceDetector` library, but, it is not to accurate if the person on the picture is not looking to the front. In some apps of the store, I saw that there is a face skin while you take the picture to guide you, so I would like to now how can I modify the camera layout to make my own guide lines. Any approach would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you to try

> OpenCV

it's open source SDK

http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html